# .htaccess redirect showing internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite query parameter to slashes separated using .htaccess

Example Rewrite

```
http:www.site.com/user/comfirm/index.php?confirm=x22xx22xxx
```

To

```
http:www.site.com/user/comfirm/x22xx22xxx
```

To do this I am trying this way

```
RewriteRule ^/user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L, QSA]
```

But it is showing internal server error.

Also tried with some variation like changing `/user/` to `user/` and like this.

```
RewriteRule ^/user/confirm/(.*)/$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L]
```

But shows 404 error

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing this rewrite rule from root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And placing another `.htaccess` file in `confirm` directory to hide index.php and processing query parameter there with following codes.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?confirm=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now its working. Hope this helps others too with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues:

Remove the space in your flags: [L,QSA]

the Pattern was also wrong, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA]
```

One easy way to debug issues with htaccess is to check your web server (Apache) logs, usuallu error_log or errors.log depending on your setup.

Comment: that will be the rewrite being incorrect, I only pointed out your errors :)

Comment: probably your regex: ([^A-Za-z0-9]) will NOT match a-z0-9 due to the negation ^ try this: ([A-Za-z0-9])

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/confirm/([^/]+)/?$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If it doesn't work then please post your complete .htaccess in your question.

**EDIT:** Suggested .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks-MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/confirm/([^/]+)/?$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

RewriteRule ^rss/(.+?)\.xml$ rss/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.+?\.html)$ /software/?pflink=$1&pagelink=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Show the error from error.log and as I asked earlier `post your complete .htaccess in your question`

Comment: There is an error.log file in Apache log directory. You need to open in whatever editor you have and see what error is being generated.

Comment: Ok, meanwhile rename your .htaccess and try my suggested .htaccess from my EDIT section above.

Comment: Ok in that you do need to read the error from Apache's error.log

Comment: I saw error.log. So error is about loading php_curl.dll which has nothing to do with rewrite rules. You need to resolve that yourself or via your hosting provider.

Comment: your code is working with url `http://localhost/user/confirm/index.php/ndsndi32cv3DDFWEFEW` but not for `http://localhost/user/confirm/ndsndi32cv3DDFWEFEW`

Comment: If you copy/paste my solution it will work the way you want. Provide your latest .htaccess with my suggested changes above.

Comment: It didn't work with index.php in url as I mentioned above, I resolved it by placing another .htaccess in confirm directory to hide index.php and now its working.